# How to prevent widgets from being hidden behind the system status bar

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

So I am creating a new flutter widget and I am unable to understand how my app looks because of the space on top of the screen in my emulator,

[image]

As you can see there is a shaded area on top and my widgets are under it, is there any way to remove it?

Comment: The reason i am not putting a padding on top is because my all my widgets are in a custom scroll view

Comment: Wrap with `SafeArea` Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Safe Area.

SafeArea is basically a glorified Padding widget. If you wrap another widget with SafeArea, it adds any necessary padding needed to keep your widget from being blocked by the system status bar, notches, holes, rounded corners, and other "creative" features by manufacturers.

Check this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) for more.

Comment: If we have scrollable content without an app bar, then SafeArea does not solve the scroll behind the status bar. Do you know how can we solve scrolling behind the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with the `SafeArea`.

more info about [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) class